# Limit with creating a drop-down list dependent on a selection in excel

Tags: excel, validation, drop-down-menu

I have an excel file with two sheets. The second sheet (**Report**) contains data validation cells based on the first sheet (**Data**). From the second sheet, the drop-down list that displays in the **Select XXX** depends on the selection in the **Generate Report**. When the **Generate Report** is set to anything beyond the first five in its list, the "Select XXX" displays year as a default list (no problem with this) via the code `...INDIRECT("Year")...`. The problem is that excel does not allow for addition of more code (seems I hit the limit). The question is - how can I manipulate this code to accommodate every option in the **Generate Report**? or perhaps, is there another method to implement?

The data validation source code for the drop-down list is `=IF($B$4=Data!$Q$5,INDIRECT("Client"), IF($B$4=Data!$Q$6,INDIRECT("Month"), IF($B$4=Data!$Q$7,INDIRECT("Product_Service"), IF($B$4=Data!$Q$8,INDIRECT("Sector"), IF($B$4=Data!$Q$9,INDIRECT("Trans_Type"),INDIRECT("Year"))))))`

Please, see the sample file at https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VKkGHjlJzLQqx4J9kyd_bCKG4r0Q7HkG/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is put the range names in column R, and VLOOKUP them:

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT(VLOOKUP($B$4,Data!$Q$5:$R$9,2,FALSE)),INDIRECT("Year"))
```

You could then have as many item lists as you wish.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked, although I didn't think the `IFERROR` function is necessary so I simply used `=INDIRECT(VLOOKUP($B$4,Data!$Q$5:$R$9,2,FALSE))`. Also interesting is the fact that unlike my initial code, it doesn't go into error even when the data in the "report basis" table is sorted